# Rotating a node up a BST depending on the access count to optimize the tree for searching

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have been running into an interesting error while building a "search optimized" BST (each node has an access count identifier). I can successfully move nodes up the tree however, some nodes do not move up the tree as many times as expected.

For example:

[image: Binary Search Tree Example]

When I call my find method on value `1` the tree successfully adjusts and 1 becomes the root. Subsequently when I call the method on `4` the node moves up to be the right child of the root `1`.

However, when I call on `5` or `6` the node only rotates upwards once, then the optimization ends.

Here is my code that optimizes the tree, it is called on the root of the tree after a node is found using the find method:

```
private void RecOptimize(TreeNode<T> currentNode, TreeNode<T> prevNode)
        {
            if (currentNode == null) return;

            RecOptimize(currentNode.left, currentNode);
            RecOptimize(currentNode.right, currentNode);

            var left = currentNode.left;
            var right = currentNode.right;
            var oldNode = currentNode;

            if(right != null)
            {
                if (right.iAccessCount > currentNode.iAccessCount)
                {
                    currentNode = MakeRightRoot(currentNode);
                }
            }
            if(left != null)
            {
                if (left.iAccessCount > currentNode.iAccessCount)
                {
                    currentNode = MakeLeftRoot(currentNode);
                }
            }
            if(prevNode != null)
            {
                if(prevNode.left != null && prevNode.left.Equals(oldNode))
                {
                    prevNode.left = currentNode;
                }

                if(prevNode.right != null && prevNode.right.Equals(oldNode))
                {
                    prevNode.right = currentNode;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.rootNode = currentNode;
            }
        }
```

**Edit** Thought I would clear something up.

`MakeLeftRoot(node)` and `MakeRightRoot(node)` simply perform a rotation about the node, `MakeLeftRoot` rotates the nodes left node and returns it. While `MakeRightRoot` does the same but to the right side.

**Edit 2** Heres the code for the rotation methods

```
        protected TreeNode<T> MakeRightRoot(TreeNode<T> oldRoot)
    {
        var newRoot = oldRoot.right;
        oldRoot.right = newRoot.left;
        newRoot.left = oldRoot;
        return newRoot;
    }

    protected TreeNode<T> MakeLeftRoot(TreeNode<T> oldRoot)
    {
        var newRoot = oldRoot.left;
        oldRoot.left = newRoot.right;
        newRoot.right = oldRoot;
        return newRoot;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: why would you go through the entire tree for this? You should do this *in* the find function since that is where the access counter is incremented (I suppose), and so that is the only path that may need rotations. Secondly, you should provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume all your other code is correct, including the functions that perform rotations. Then there is still this issue in `RecOptimize`:

If `currentNode` changes by the call of `MakeRightRoot(currentNode)`, then the `left` and `right` variables no longer represent the left and right nodes of `currentNode` and so the next `if` block will not be doing what is intended, as at that moment `left` is a grandchild of `currentNode`.

I understand why you also pass `prevNode` to this function, and how the `if(prevNode != null)` block is dealing with setting the link with `prevNode` and the potentially changed reference for `currentNode`, but it will be much easier if you use the same coding pattern as for your rotation functions: let the function *return* the potentially changed reference for `currentNode`, and let the caller be responsible for attaching that node back to its parent node.

Also, you should determine whether it is possible that a higher access count occurs in *both* subtrees of a node or not. If it cannot occur (because after each access you call this function), then you may want to use an `if ...else if` construct for the two first blocks. If however it *could* occur, then think how you want the tree to get rotated. I believe it is better to then to deal with each subtree separately: first finish the work for one subtree completely (recursive call + potential rotation), and *then* only deal with the other subtree (recursive call + potential rotation).

Here is the suggested code:

```
private TreeNode<T> RecOptimize(TreeNode<T> node) {
    if (node == null) return null;

    if (node.right != null) {
        node = RecOptimize(node.right);
        if (node.right.iAccessCount > node.iAccessCount) {
            node = MakeRightRoot(node);
        }
    }
    if (node.left != null) {
        node = RecOptimize(node.left);
        if (node.left.iAccessCount > node.iAccessCount) {
            node = MakeLeftRoot(node);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Main call:

```
this.rootNode = RecOptimize(this.rootNode);
```

One more comment: `RecOptimize` is going to visit every node in the tree. This is not optimal. If you access a node through binary search, then you should only have to check for rotations along the path to that found node, as a "bubble up" phase.

Comment: This solution does work, but now I think I have an issue in my rotations. I posted the code, sorry for omitting it before. Also, where would I call this during the bubble up phase? I have a hard time figuring out where the recursive backtracking happens, if you have any reading on it that would be amazing!

Comment: May I suggest you ask a new, dedicated question on the rotations, with an example where the problem becomes apparent?  And if you cannot make the bubbling up version work, can you ask yet another question about that showing your work, and where you are stuck?